# How to eager load multiple relationships and group by a nested relation

Tags: php, laravel

In a sports app, I want to display a list of teams and the players in each team, and have the players grouped by their position.

Here's how the model relationships are defined.

Each Position is linked to a Sport. In Football you'd have CF, ST, GK, etc. In Basketball you'd have PG, PF, C, etc.

```php
class Sport {

  public function positions()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Position::class);
  }

}
```

The Position class knows about every Player that plays the Position.

```php
class Position {

  public function sport()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Sport::class);
  }

  public function players()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Player::class);
  }

}
```

Each Player can play a specific Position on a single Team.

```php
class Player {

  public function position()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Position::class);
  }

  public function team()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Team::class);
  }

}
```

And each Team is directly related to a Sport and each Player can play a Position on that Team.

```php
class Team {

  public function sport()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Sport::class);
  }

  public function players()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Player::class);
  }

}
```

Now, here's my issue. I want to return a list of teams, with the positions being played on each team, and the players playing each position on that team. My desired response would look something like this.

```
{
  "teams": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Barcelona",
      "positions": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Center Forward",
          "players": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "Lionel Messi"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried a variety of approaches but I can't seem to get it right. The code below ends up giving me an acceptable structure, but the players aren't filtered by team, so I get all the players that play the position, regardless of the team. By example, the Goalkeeper position would contain keepers from all teams which is definitely wrong.

```php
Team::with(['sport.positions.players'])->paginate();
```

I feel like it might be something like this.

```php
Team::with(['players.position' => function ($query) { /* insert groupBy magic */ }])->paginate();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to define Sport.Teams relationship to see if it works

Comment: There is no direct relation between `Team` and `Position`. without a relation, it is hard to form the json you wanted. are you okay with the json `teams->sports->positions->players`?

Comment: @SandeepSudhakaran yes, that's totally fine with me, but when I try something to that effect, I end up getting players per position from ALL the teams in the same array. For some reason the players are not scope to the team when I get them with that approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should get your teams then load other data to it:

```
$teams->load('sport.positions.players');
```

**Note**: use **paginate count** in your paginate function as a **parameter** like this:

```
$teams->load('sport.positions.players')->paginate(5);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this:

`$this->teams = \App\Team::all();`

`$this->teams = $this->teams->load('sport.positions.players');`

But this ends up loading (within each team object) ALL the players for each position, without respecting the team_id. Basically I end up with players for various teams in the same array for each team.

Answer (score 0):

Not ***exactly*** what you want, but this should give you something close enough.

start by defining a `teams` relation on the `App\Sport`

```php
public function teams()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Team::class);
}
```

And then instead of going *Sport -> Position -> Players* go *Sport -> Teams -> Players*, this way you'll get scoping for the players per team for free and you can then group each team players by their `position` like so

```php
Sport::with(['teams.players.position'])->find($sport_id)
    ->setRelation('teams',  $sport->teams->map(function($team){
        return $team->setRelation('players', $team->players->groupBy(function($player){
            return $player->position->name;
        }));
    }));
```

the `setRelation()` is to overwrite the relation instead of adding an *attribute* with the name of the relation to the model instance.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can try below query:

```
$team = Team::with(['players','position'=>function($q){
   $q->groupBy('positio_name') ;
})->get();
```